# Mean values from multiple tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table

I have 15 years of monthly air pollution values in multiple monthly tables I interpolated and then summarized by table for each census division in ArcGIS.  I want to summarize the mean monthly values into yearly then map out the yearly values in ArcGIS.  (i.e. take 12 tables and calculate mean yearly values).  Each table has a pollution value and unique census id.  Any ideas the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was using model builder -- Iterate tables and join field based on the census id and mean values for join fields.

The only issue all yearly values need to be in their own geodatabase -- so need to copy them into a geodatabase for each year.